# AWS Lambda environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, aws-lambda

To reduce the cost on instances, we were looking for options. 
AWS lambda seems to be a good option for us.
Its still in the preliminary stage of searching for available alternatives.

My concern is if we switch some of our applications to lambda, we will be confined to use AWS environments only , and in future it might become a boundation for a scenario , which we cant predict at the moment.

So my question is, is there a way that we can still use lambda in an environment which is not an AWS environment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda functions are basically containers, where its lifecycle is managed by Amazon.

When you use Lambda, there are several best practices you can follow, to avoid full locking. One of the recommended practice is to separate the business logic from Lambda handler. When you separate the Lambda handler, it only works as the controller which points to the executing code.

```
/handler.js
/lib
  /create-items
  /list-items
```

For example, if you design a web application API this way with NodeJS in Lambda, you can later move the business logic to an ExpressJS server by moving the handler code to ExpressJS Routes.

As you can see, you will still require putting additional effort to move an application from Lambda to another environment. By properly designing, you can only reduce the efforts.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, 
Its AWS lambda function, so it is suppose to be deployed on AWS instances only, because they support the needed environment.

From AWS site there are couple of options ...
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/deploying-lambda-apps.html